# KNN finds equal distances between datapoints after normalization

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, knn

I'm using the fifa players dataset to build a ML model that should find similar players. To this model I'm using KNN, but when I use data normalization it always find the same distance between datapoints. Look the exemple below:

With normalization:

```
#3.4 - Rescaling values

from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

scaler = MinMaxScaler() # I tried StandardScaler too

X_model = scaler.fit_transform(X)

from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors
model = NearestNeighbors(algorithm='brute', n_neighbors=10)
model.fit(X_model) #X to use dataset without normalization

# 4 - Presenting results

from ipywidgets import widgets, interact
from IPython.display import display

dp_players = df[['name','id']].sort_values(by=['name']).values.tolist()

def get_similars(Player):
  distance, similar_players_index = model.kneighbors(X.loc[Player].values.reshape(1,-1))
  similar_players = pd.DataFrame()
  similar_players = df.loc[df.index[similar_players_index[0]]]
  similar_players['distances'] = [int(x) for x in distance[0]]
  return similar_players[['name', 'club', 'overall','distances']]
```

[image]

When i do not use scalers I have more realistict results and distances, See:

[image]

How can I reach the same results with the normalized dataset?
here's my notebook https://github.com/tiagosilveiraa/portifoliods/blob/main/Players_Recomendation_using_fifa22_dataset.ipynb

Comment: `get_similars()` indexes `X`, but `model.fit()` accepts `X_model`. That is, the model is fit to min-max-scaled data, but you're evaluating it on unscaled data.

Comment: @AlexanderGuyer, I tried this solution this error is raised 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'loc'"

Answer (score -1):

I noticed that i was fitting the model with scaled data, and evaluating it on unescaled data.

To solve this problem I made this

```
##3.2 - Rescaling values

from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

scaler = MinMaxScaler()

X_scaled = pd.DataFrame()

X_scaled[X.columns.values] =  scaler.fit_transform(X[X.columns.values])

X_scaled.index = X['id']

X_scaled.drop(columns=['id'], inplace=True)

##3.3 - Creating model

from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors
model = NearestNeighbors(algorithm='brute', n_neighbors=10)
model.fit(X_scaled.values)

# 4 - Presenting results

from ipywidgets import widgets, interact
from IPython.display import display

dp_players = df[['name','id']].sort_values(by=['name']).values.tolist()

def get_similars(Player):
  distance, similar_players_index = model.kneighbors(X_scaled.loc[Player].values.reshape(1,-1))  
  similar_players = pd.DataFrame()
  similar_players = df.loc[df.index[similar_players_index[0]]]
  similar_players['distances'] = distance[0]
  return similar_players[['name', 'club', 'overall','distances']]

interact(get_similars, Player=dp_players);
```

Now the results are correct

Comment: It's not at all clear to me what's going on here or why/how it solves this question.